# Unable to read a global object in a function

Tags: jquery

I added a global object in which I am inserting my json through jquery getjson.
Now I want to use this in an if condition inside a function.
I have declared it as a parameter of the function but still I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: jsonData is undefined
```

It would be great if someone can sort out the problem. Here is my function:

```
function getConcept(jsonData){

    $('a').click(function() {

                var clickedItem = $(this).attr('title');
                if(jsonData.icon!=null){
                    var concept = clickedItem;
                    identifiedObjectsList.push(concept);
                    console.log(identifiedObjectsList);
                    $("#Boma").append($("<img>", {"src": "Boma.png" ,"style": "width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:" +
                        x + "px; top:" + y + "px;"}));
                }
                else {
                    var concept = undefined;
                }
                    console.log(concept);
        });
    };
```

I am getting this error in the if condition.

This is how I am calling getConcept:

```
function varCallBack(){
        $.each(json_data.menu, function () {
        $menu.append(
            getMenuItem(this)
        );

            getConcept(json_data);

    });
```

Below is the declaration of the global object and then the inserting of json into it:

```
var json_data = {};

jQuery.getJSON("/concepts2.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        json_data = data;
        varCallBack();

         });
```

Here is my json:

```
{
"menu": [{

        "name": "concepts",
        "id": "1",
        "icon": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "land characteristic",
                "id": "1.1",
                "icon": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "school",
                        "id": "1.1.1",
                        "icon": "/black images/Other buildings.png",
                        "children": null
                    }
                    {
                        "name": "house",
                        "id": "1.1.2",
                        "icon": null,
                        "children": null
                    }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us how you're calling `getConcept`

Comment: It's because `jsonData` has not been defined. Most likely because you've called `getConcept` with an undefined argument.

Comment: I am calling it inside a function which I wrote for a call back. getConcept();

Comment: @adeneo check the edit in the question. Does this help?

Comment: try me answer bellow it's working

Comment: Yes, it helps, you're calling the function with no arguments, so `jsonData` is undefined.

Comment: @adeneo Check now. Is this correct? I am not getting the error anymore but now the if condition does seem to work and the debugger is jumping direct to the else condition, ignoring the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference global variable on the click even because jsonData is local function variable and it will be destroyed after function call

```
function getConcept(){
$('a').click(function() {

            var clickedItem = $(this).attr('title');
            var concept;
            if(json_data.icon!=null){
                concept = clickedItem;
                identifiedObjectsList.push(concept);
                console.log(identifiedObjectsList);
                $("#Boma").append($("<img>", {"src": "Boma.png" ,"style": "width:25px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:" +
                    x + "px; top:" + y + "px;"}));
            }
            else {
                concept = undefined;
            }
                console.log(concept);
    });
};
```

and your call to this function like bellow

```
function varCallBack(){
    $.each(json_data.menu, function () {
    $menu.append(
        getMenuItem(this)
    );
        getConcept();

});

var json_data;

jQuery.getJSON("/concepts2.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    json_data = data;
    varCallBack();

     });
```

Comment: I am already adding a global object and adding my json into it. Now I just need to call it in this function.

Comment: delete getConcept parameter and reference your global object

Comment: see my edit now. Your global object name must be jsonData

Comment: I have named my global variable json_data. I am now passing json_data when the function getConept is being called. Shouldn't it copy all that is in json_data now to jsonData?

Comment: jsonData is local varaible for the function and it destroyed after function call and a click event occur later so it dosn't found it

Comment: Check the question now. Can you edit your answer according to that?

Comment: I have tried your way. I am not getting the error anymore but now the if condition does seem to work and the debugger is jumping direct to the else condition, ignoring the if condition. Can you help out with that?

Comment: It contains my json

Comment: Issue relate to your json data